# Jasig CAS Single Sign Out - Logout

Tags: logout, cas, jasig

I'm currently making tests with the CAS server 3.5.2 and I'm facing
problems with the logout.
My knowledge in these topics is limited and I don't manage to go further on
that point.

I installed a CAS server and I've got 2 instances of the same java
application that point to that CAS server (appologize if I don't use the
adecuates terms).
So, when I access to the protected resources of my client aplication, I'm
redirected to the CAS login page, I check in my DB if credentials are ok
and then I access the resource. Then, if I access to the same protected
resource from the second instance of the client application I'm not
redirected to login page. That's perfect.

The problem is situated in the logout. To do so, I first execute a
session.invalidate() and access to the CAS logout page. It's ok because,
from the application from which I logged out, I must login again to access
the protected resources. On the other side, the second application remains
connected and I can access the protected resources without login again.
Well, I know that the session.invalidate() is local to the first
application but I thought that CAS server would have "broadcasted" the
desconnexion to the other application but no.

Is there somebody who can give me experience feedback for the single sing
out topic ?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that SSO is enabled in the CAS properties file, if not make sure the SSO Listener is enabled in the clients.
If they are enabled then my guess would be the issue is in either the LogoutManagerImpl.java or SamlCompliantLogoutMessageCreator.java files.

The SSO in CAS is performed through the back-channel by transmitting a SAML XML message.
I had an issue with the SSO function last year only to find out that the XML message being broadcasted had an error that prevented it from being parsed.

Comment: Thank you for you time. I answered my question (my problem was due to wrong filters order in web.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved...
In web.xml, the order of filters is important. Filters for Single-sign out must be placed at the begining.
See that section https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/CAS+Client+for+Java+3.1#CASClientforJava3.1-OrderofRequiredFilters